# Scrapy - How to fix "Please enable cookies" when cookies are already enabled?

Tags: python, cookies, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl a website for shoes for an university project. From the code below I get 3-4 shoes, but after that, for the remaining shoes I get the response "Please enable cookies", even though I set `Cookies_enabled=True` and `Cookies_debug=True`. Where is the problem?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request


class FirespiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'firespider'
    page_number = 2
    allowed_domains = ['kicksonfire.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.kicksonfire.com/app/upcoming?page=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        shoe_links = response.xpath ('//div/a/@href').extract()[1:None]
        for link in shoe_links:
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_page, dont_filter=True)


    def parse_page(self, response):
        shoe_name = response.xpath('//div/h2/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        print('Schuh:' + shoe_name)
```

[First part of the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mxiG.png)
[Response "Please enable cookies" in the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXjCa.png)

Comment: your code works can you share any settings you edited?

Comment: @wishmaster so you don't get the "Please enable cookies" in the terminal? I changed the `User_Agent='Chrome 80.0.3987.149 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0)'` , changed the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY=25.0` and `COOKIES_ENABLED=TRUE` as well as `COOKIES_DEBUG=TRUE`. And `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False`.

Comment: Yes,it worked fine for me try setting a proxy

Comment: @wishmaster thank you for the confirmation that it's working. Unfortunately it's not working also with proxy... I'm beginner at crawling, but could it be that it's down to the browser?

Comment: Do you have `COOKIES_ENABLED` anywhere in your code? Can you share the entire line and surrounding lines of the “Please enable cookies” message from your log? Are you running your spider on Scrapy Cloud or a similar service?

Comment: @Gallaecio, thanks for offering your help. I haven't found a solution for this problem, so I changed the website and everything workes perfectly now with the different website. The scraped data is slightly different now but still good. My code worked for wishmaster and my friend but not for me. Idk what the problem was. Thank you though, highly appreciated.